# Find sum of $5$ digit number that can be formed using digits $0,0,1,2,3,4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm attaching my approach in image format. I'm new to mathematics stack exchange, so I'm not able to write in latex format properly.
I'm getting different answers. what going wrong in my logic.
I've solved every problem related to sum by this way.

Given answer is $6399960$.[image]
**strong text**

Comment: When you calculated the sum, you should have gotten $12 \ 888 \ 800$ with an extra zero at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that a digit of $0$ does not contribute anything to the sum, so you do not need to count them.

For the first digit, you should have $\frac{120}{2!} = 60$, as both zeroes are indistinguishable, so they give the same number when interchanged. For the other digits, you should have $\frac{3 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2}{2!} = 36$ instead of $80$ for the same reason, as the factor of $1$ for the chosen digit does not affect the calculation  (the first digit cannot be $0$ as you have noticed).

Hence the answer is ($1+2+3+4=10$):

$$60 \times 10 \times 10^4 + 36 \times 10 \times 10^3 + 36 \times 10 \times 10^2 + 36 \times 10 \times 10^1 +  36 \times 10 \times 10^0$$
$$=6399 960.$$

or around $6$ million.

Comment: You can estimate the answer by taking the average of the lowest and highest numbers, and then multiplying by the total possible number. This gives $\frac{1}{2} (43210 + 10234) \cdot 240 = 6 \ 413 \ 280$, which is quite close to the actual number.

Comment: you said "for the fist digit ,you should have $60$" but in that case dont you include zero as first digit ? So, it break to be five digits number

Comment: That's not true. We choose the first digit to calculate the number of permutations *for each digit*. So for the first digit, we have $1$ choice which is not $0$ ($1,2,3,4$). Then there are $\frac{5 * 4 * 3 *2}{2!} = 60$ ways to choose the other digits. This means that there are $60$ ways per digit, which is not $60$ ways in total.

Comment: got my mistake....thanks

Comment: @TobyMak how did you get $3*4*3*2/2!$

Comment: For example, for the second digit, there are $3$ choices for the first digit, $1$ choices for  the second, $4$ choices for the third, $3$ choices for the fourth, and $2$ choices for the last. We have $3 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2$ for all the digits because multiplying by $1$ does not change the number. We divide by $2!$ because the $2$ zeroes are interchangeable.